# like operator in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch the data from database using `like` operator.If I use static value i got the answer  but using dynamically I can't fetch it.Any body know the answer please help.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE the_number LIKE '2016-01-09%'");
function calendercheck($data)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE start_date LIKE '$data%'");
    return($query->result());
}
```

Comment: What datatype is your `start_date` column?

Comment: I am using datetime.

Comment: Then don't use LIKE..... LIKE is intended for use with strings

Comment: Then how can i fetch the date

Comment: `SELECT * from events WHERE startdate = '2016-03-21'` or `SELECT * from events WHERE startdate >= '2016-03-21' AND startdate <= '2016-03-22'` or `SELECT * from events WHERE startdate BETWEEN '2016-03-21' AND '2016-03-22'` or similar

Comment: echo the query and see what it prints

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WHERE docdate BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'` for filter data in mysql.

Comment: Actually  I stored some dates in my table.that format is 2016-01-09.

Comment: but my dynamic date contain this format 09-01-2016.how can i fetch.I don't  want from and to date

Comment: using query i have to fetch the row regarding the date

Comment: WHERE DATE(signup_date) = CURDATE()